# swagger-ui adds api_token to query twice in CURL example

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am setting up our api documentation and i'm using swagger-spec and swagger ui.

I got everything working except that my CURL example adds our access_token twice

```
curl -X DELETE --header "Accept: application/json" "http://api host/api/user?filter%5Bid%5D%5BEQUAL%5D=1&access_token=Token_TOKANE&access_token=Token_TOKANE"
```

I renamed the api_key in swagger_ui index

```
var apiKeyAuth = new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("access_token", key, "query"); 
window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("access_token", apiKeyAuth);
```

Screenshot
[image]

Swagger delete path

```
delete:
  tags:
    - User
  summary: Delete user from you organization
  operationId: deleteUser
  description: Deletes a single by id. Gets id from filter param in query
  parameters:
    - name: filter[id][EQUAL]
      in: query
      type: integer
      required: true
      description: id to delete
  responses:
    200:
      description: OK
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Message'
  security:
    - access_token: []
```

Security definition

```
securityDefinitions:
  access_token:
    type: string
    in: query
    name: access_token
```

The same issue can be seen in the swagger-ui [live demo](http://petstore.swagger.io/)

If anyone knows of a fix or workaround i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has just been addressed in [swagger-js](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/pull/633).  You can update your swagger-ui by building this locally and using `npm link` against the local build of swagger-ui.  The release of swagger-ui with this fix is coming soon.